# Is there a difference in the meaning of this sentence if I put "according to" at the beginning of the second dpd clause vs at the end of the sentence?

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-meaning, sentence-choice

I want to say

1. Taliban is never trustable
2. Taliban was a supporter of Xinjiang islamist militants (source: [China](https://web.archive.org/web/20210730180722/http://www.china.org.cn/english/2002/Jan/25582.htm))

I wrote this sentence:

> Taliban is never trustable, and they were one of the supporters of Xinjiang islamist militants, [according to China](https://web.archive.org/web/20210730180722/http://www.china.org.cn/english/2002/Jan/25582.htm).

I have a feeling the sentence I wrote incorrectly claimed that the hyperlinked government study said Taliban is never trustable. Had I put the "according to" at the start of the second dependent clause, my sentence would convey the intended message correctly. Am I correct?

> Taliban is never trustable, and [according to China](https://web.archive.org/web/20210730180722/http://www.china.org.cn/english/2002/Jan/25582.htm), they were one of the supporters of Xinjiang islamist militants.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. The second sentence makes the intended meaning much clearer.

Comment: N.B. We say "The Taliban" in English. And "trustable" is a less common way to say the preferred "trustworthy" or "can be trusted".